# Attempt to include header file in Xcode 5. File not found

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to include a header file in my xcode 5 project. The file path is
`/Users/ceid/Desktop/test.h`

`#include "/User/ceid/Desktop/test.h"` works

When I attempt to use `#include "test.h"` and put `/Users/ceid/Desktop` in my header search paths, the file is not found.

I have also tried User Search Paths.
I have also tried both quotes and angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there are two general ways of include files.

`#include "file"`: include the file searching in the same directory of the file containing the line. Some compiler and IDE, when not find the file fallback to the second option (ex: VC++)
`#include <file>`: include the file searching in the includes path added (-I option in GCC).

The recommended use is, `#include "file"`, for files in the same context (same library, same module etc...), use `#include <file>` for external files (external in the sense of context, not in the sense of code not yours, example:

two libraries, **crypto** and **datetime**, if you want to include **datetime** in **crypto** use `#include <file>`, even if the two libreries are yours, and siting next to each other in disk, because tomorrow probably want to reorganize the libraries, grouped better, etc...